# GPS latitude, longitude, elevation, and Total Station's Coordinates - can they be used together?

Tags: gps, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, land-survey, total-station

I have used DGPS to get the coordinates (lat, long) using UTM projection, and elevation (height above ellipsoid) for different points (set a). If I use one of the collected points location to setup total station, and feed the GPS coordinates inside the total station then collect the measurements of other points (set b). Can I use these set a, and set b points together? For example georeferencing of UAV. The reason I am asking this is GPS coordinates are projected from ellipsoid projection of earth, where as the total station coordinates are based on simple angle, and distance calculations. Is it right to use them together? or do i need to do any processing for total station coordinates

Comment: No, this won't work. Your UTM coordinates have a grid scale factor and elevation factor, so they won't match ground distances. What software are you using?

Comment: I am using path finder for correcting dgps data. Total station data and corrected dgps data we are planning to use as GCP's in ArcGIS.

Comment: Most data collectors for total station have an option to use a combined scale factor. (grid scale factor X elevation factor)